# Can people from outside the airport visit me inside the airport while I'm in transit in the Sheremetyevo International Airport, Russia?

Tags: svo

I'll be there for a 15 hour layover from overseas on my way to another final destination.

Comment: There's always people inside SVO meeting and greeting people who have arrived, but I think you might mean air side. If that's the case, no.

Comment: @GayotFow usual trick of refundable plane ticket 6-12 hours later, pass security, cancel? Or is that not working in Russia?

Comment: @chx I never tried that, but sure, why not?

Answer (score 1):

They can if you exit the secured area of the airport. However, you will need to print your boarding pass for your connecting flight and go through security again to board your connecting flight.

Answer (score 1):

The usual trick to facilitate this is to buy a refundable plane ticket for a flight like 6-12 hours later, pass security, and cancel it. Read the fine print on when and how can you cancel, though, consider you will need to check in to get the boarding pass.